# How can I improve the performance of static data caching in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, asp.net-web-api

Our site has a large number of lists of constants for fields such as address type descriptions, states, generic comments, boolean type values, gender, etc...

We would like to be able to have this data available on all of our pages or at least the relevant lists given the page being loaded.

Our architecture consists of client side HTTP and Ajax requests hitting our MVC4 controller actions where those actions then query the Web API and retrieves data from the database etc.

We have decided to go with http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-at-application-startup-cs as well as some client side caching.

Is there anything else we can do so we can have these values on the client with even less overhead? Should we cache on controller methods (essentially caching what's inside HttpRuntime.Cache?

thanks

Comment: I'm curious as to why there have been two votes to close and no explanation. I'm genuinely trying to understand what the major differences between these types of caching are. If it truly isn't a good question please explain why instead of just trying to close it.

Comment: @MikroDel I have read the faq and I think this is a valid question.

Comment: Hey edhedges, I think you do have a good question in here, but you need to focus it a bit - maybe limit your question to just the architectures you've examined, or focus on the problem you're trying to solve rather than asking for a pro/con list of designs.

Comment: I will look into editing it a bit.

Comment: I've edited further, and reopened.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks! I didn't even think about editing the title. I appreciate it.

Comment: @edhedges I'm interested in this too, so added a small bounty with the hope of getting a few answers!

Comment: @JMK thanks! I felt that it could be relevant to many people because in almost any app there are going to be constants and I believe it's important to be able to have those constants easily available at different locations in ones architecture.

Comment: No problem. Like a lot of people, I love the MVC architecture and fully understand why MVC frameworks like ASP MVC and ROR etc are better than the likes of WebForms with it's evil session state, but how do you get around making the same expensive database calls repeatedly when nothing has changed in a non-hackish way?

Comment: Are you using localStorage at client side for caching? And how are you managing different versions of cache? I would recommend using some sort of versioning to avoid hitting dirty data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the ideas that you have for caching are good ideas, lookup lists data that does not change often or can be predicted consistent list by user id for example are all candidates for caching

By client side caching, I can't tell if you are using output caching or something else but I would look at output caching where appropriate

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "id")]
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
```

Two small points about output caching

1. Try to use VaryByParam, this insures that if the data changes the cached output doesn't become stale
2. Try to pick a reasonable time for duration, otherwise cache can only be refreshed if the app pool is recycled

More information about output caching can be found here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: So if I have VarByParam for two params and duration int.MaxValue for the same request will the code in the method actually get executed or does it get the value from the cache? How can I tell when I'm debugging?

Comment: If cache rule evaluates to true the method will not execute, I have not found a way to check that output caching is using a cached set of values with the debugger